# how to use a python generator expression as a function return value?

Tags: python, generator

i am a python newbie. i am trying to run this code snippet to make a list of range values using generator expression in order to use as numpy.histogram second argument ('a' and 'b' are non-negative integers).

```
return ([b] + [(b - a) / 2.0 ** k for k in xrange(1, n)] + [a])[::-1]
```

but i get a type error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Untitled Document 1.py", line 25, in <module>
create_bins(a = 0, b = 10)
File "Untitled Document 1.py", line 19, in creat_bins
return ((b) + ((b - a) / 2.0 ** k for k in xrange(1, n)) + (a))[::-1]
TypeError: an integer is required
```

i have searched questions and answers and read lots of details on python generators but i could not find out what the problem is.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

a generator expression would use `yield`.

If I use your code (with `range` instead of `xrange`), this works:

```
def test(a,b,n):
  yield ([b] + [(b - a) / 2.0 ** k for k in range(1, n)] + [a])[::-1]

for i in test(1,2,3):
    print(i)
```